# QTP set dynamic action and repository path

Tags: qtp

I'm working on QTP avec web add-in. I would like to know if there is a way to set the action and repository path dynamically. Because when I copy all the test in different machines, if the paths of the repository or reuse actions are not the same, I have to open each test to reset the path in missing resources. If this idea cannot be done within QTP, is there any other language, like c# could do this kind of thing? 
Thanks a lot in advance.

Allen

Comment: Could someone please light me a little?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can load actions dynamically by using the `LoadAndRunAction` function (available since QTP10) and you can load shared object repositories by using `RepositoriesCollection.Add`.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't need to do this, so I don't know the exact answer.

Have you looked at AutomationObjectModel.chm and Utility.chm docs that are installed along with QTP?
Utility.chm has RepositoriesCollections object and LoadAndRunAction Statement that can help you. AutomationObjectModel.chm has various Action* objects.